# Boton para descargar archivo pdf desde dispositivo movil

Tags: javascript, reactjs

el planteo que estoy haciendo para el boton curriculum, es que si es un dispositivo movil, descargue el archivo y si es computadora, que abra el componente PDF en otra pestaña para verlo.

El problema surge unicamente cuando quiero descargarlo, lo demas funciona.
Cuando lo quiero descargar y lo pruebo desde inspeccionar elemento, en el emulador para movil del navegador. FUNCIONA

Pero cuando lo quiero presionar el boton desde mi celular, no hace nada. he tratado pero no encuentro la falla.

```
introducir el código aquí



 const DescargarPdf = () =>{
    const isMobileDevice = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    const pdfUrl = '../pdf/cv.pdf';

    if (isMobileDevice) {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = require(pdfUrl);
        link.rel = 'noopener noreferrer'; 
        link.download = 'cv.pdf';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    } else {
        // Abre la página en dispositivos no móviles
        window.open('/pdf', '_blank');
    }
}
```

y este es el boton donde llamo a la funcion en react js

```
introducir el código aquí

         <a className='btn btn-danger'  onClick={()=>{DescargarPdf()}}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon className='me-1' icon={faFilePdf} />
                Curriculum</a>
```

Edito lo siguiente, agregue este codigo. se descarga el archivo correctamente pero cuando trato de abrirlo dice el siguiente mensaje. "Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF." por las dudas el archivo pdf esta bien y funciona.

```
introducir el código aquí

const DescargarPdf = async () => {
    const isMobileDevice = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (isMobileDevice) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("../pdf/HollensteinFrancoCV.pdf");

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Error al descargar el archivo PDF: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
            }

            const blob = await response.blob();
            const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = blobUrl;
            link.rel = 'noopener noreferrer';
            link.download = 'HollensteinFrancoCV.pdf';

            // Agrega el enlace al cuerpo del documento antes de simular el clic
            document.body.appendChild(link);

            // Simula clic en el enlace directamente
            link.click();

            // Elimina el enlace después del clic
            document.body.removeChild(link);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al descargar el archivo PDF:', error);
        }
    }else {
        // Abre la página en dispositivos no móviles
        window.open('/pdf', '_blank');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

lo solucione de la siguiente forma, por si alguien le sirve. el pdf lo moví a la carpeta "public" de react, al principio tenia error porque estaba fuera del src. pero se soluciono solo luego. El anterior codigo me traia la url o la ruta con error, ya que no lo encontraba.

y el codigo es el siguiente:

```
introducir el código aquí


const DescargarPdf = async () => {
    const isMobileDevice = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (isMobileDevice) {
        try {
            const pdfUrl = "/documento.pdf"; // Ruta relativa desde la raíz del servidor

            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = pdfUrl;
            link.target = '_blank';
            link.download = 'CV.pdf'; // Nombre que tendrá el archivo al descargarse
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al descargar el archivo PDF:', error);
        }
    }else {
        // Abre la página en dispositivos no móviles
        window.open('/pdf', '_blank');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te sirveria

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Descargar o Abrir PDF</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <h1>Descargar o Abrir PDF</h1>
    <button id="descargarPDF">Descargar o Abrir PDF</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("descargarPDF").addEventListener("click", function () {
      var esDispositivoMovil = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

      if (esDispositivoMovil) {
        // Si es un dispositivo móvil, descarga el archivo
        window.location.href = "ruta/tu-archivo.pdf";
      } else {
        // Si es una computadora, abre el PDF en una nueva pestaña
        window.open("ruta/tu-archivo.pdf", "_blank");
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: he tratado de esa forma, nose si es por mi codigo, pero cuando es dispositivo movil. es como que abre nuevamente mi pagina de inicio con los componentes pero vacia, sin nada adentro, solo con el nav. Pero trate con el siguiente codigo, me lo descarga al archivo pero cuando quiero abrirlo dice "Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF." voy a subir el nuevo codigo que me permite llegar a esa parte

Comment: por lo que estaba chequeando, el primer codigo no me lo descarga porque dice que la ruta no es valida, lo raro es que probe de todas las formas. y con el blob url, me trae un http://localhost:3000... que cuando quiero abrirlo me salta la pagina de inicio vacia, no me trae el pdf. puse el console.log(blob) y obtengo del tipo text el blob. nose si te servira de guia para que me ayudes